# Работа с таблицей

Tags: html, javascript

Есть таблица 128 на 128 ячеек, нужно добавить возможность выделять ячейки и передавать этот список в ссылке.

Нужен код выделения ячейки, изменение цвета или добавление рамки. Код для добавления/убирания из списка выделенных. Код ссылки, при нажатии на которую, будут переданы номера выделенных ячеек.

Comment: @mikelsv,  Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

---
сессия что-ли на носу ?

Comment: Решил в кой-то веке сначала спросить, а потом делать.
Это не сессия, это бот. )

Comment: а в чем вопрос-то ? напишите код за меня ?